# Getting a a.foreach is not a function error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to build a multiselect list using angular js. I am getting a weird TypeError: a.foreach is not a function and I can’t seem to figure out when.

js :

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('multiselect', []);

 myAppModule.controller("view", function ($scope) {
$scope.listA = {
    values: [{
        id: 1,
        label: 'aLabel',
        subItem: {
            name: 'aSubItem'
        }
}, {
        id: 2,
        label: 'bLabel',
        subItem: {
            name: 'bSubItem'
        }
}],
    selected: {
        name: 'aSubItem'
    }

};


})
```

html:

```
 <select multiple ng-options="item.subItem as item.label for item in listA.values track by item.id" ng-model="listA.selected"></select>
```

I don’t know what I could be doing wrong. Am I casting something wrong ?

Comment: I am using AngularJS v1.4.4

Comment: You can check jsfiddle for reference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that since you have added the `multiple` attribute, the value of the select should be an array. So try something similar to this:

```
$scope.listA = {
    values: [{
        id: 1,
        label: 'aLabel',
        subItem: {
            name: 'aSubItem'
        }
    }, {
        id: 2,
        label: 'bLabel',
        subItem: {
            name: 'bSubItem'
        }
    }],
    selected: [{
        name: 'aSubItem'
    }]

};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need not to track your values by id. it will do it by default.

```
<div ng-controller="Main">
    <select multiple ng-options="item.subItem as item.label for item in listA.values" ng-model="listA.selected"></select> 
</div>
```

JS Fiddle for your code (Fix):

http://jsfiddle.net/juag4okg/

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. It worked well by creating the static `json object` as answered above, but did not worked out when i tried to fetched the object or list from the server.
*Then i realized my server was not sending the `json object` and i hadn't convert it to `json` as well. And when i converted it to `json` it worked perfectly fine.*

So if you are having similar problem to display the select options (muliple or single) from the server side data this process might help you.

here is the link to angular [`angular.toJson()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson) function.