# Angular Chosen - a.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, foreach, angular-chosen

Using Angular Chosen to allow a multi select drop down for nationalities.
https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen

I am getting an error of

"a.forEach is not a function"

This error occurs whether you have selected one, two or zero options.

I have looked at this post

[Getting a a.foreach is not a function error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174145/getting-a-a-foreach-is-not-a-function-error)

however my selected value is already an array so it does not provide any help on the issue.

Here is my html

```
<li class="form-row">
                <span class="label">
                    <label for="nation">Nationality</label>:
                </span>
                <div class="field country">
                    <select 
                    chosen
                    multiple
                    ng-model='person.nation'
                    ng-options='c.name as c.name for c in countries'
                    id="nation" 
                    data-select-max="2" 
                    data-token="Nationalities" 
                    data-placeholder="- Select your nationalities -">
                    </select>
                </div>
            </li>
```

And my options ($scope.countries) looks like

```
[ 
  { id="1",  name="United States"}, 
  { id="2185",  name="Afghanistan"},
  etc....
 ]
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: It assumes that countries is an array, and {} isn't an array.

Comment: If I do 'console.log($scope.countries.constructor === Array)' it returns true

Comment: You're right. Didn't see the brackets. Some good suggestions are found here : https://github.com/wangshijun/angular-bootstrap-chosen/issues/1

Answer (score 2):

The properties of the array objects should be assigned like this: `id:"1", name:"United States"`, instead of `id="1"`. Replace the equal sign (=) with colon (:).

Also you should use forEach function in the following way:

```
angular.forEach($scope.countries, function(key, value){
// your code here
 });
```

and not as a function of the array: `$scope.countries.forEach(...)`

Comment: You are correct, however changing it so does not remove the forEach error!

Comment: I think in your code you are invoking forEach as it is a function of the array itself. The correct use is `angular.forEach($scope.countries, function(key, value){
   // your code here
  });`
See [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) for more details

Comment: The forEach function is being called from the chosen library, not as part of my own implementation. It is called using "angular.forEach". The library can be viewed in the first link of my post.

Comment: Can you share the whole code and markup, cause I cannot reproduce your issue in any other way then the one I mentioned above.